# Как использовать переменные в SASS?

Tags: sass

Есть такой код

```
.image
    position: relative
    @for $i from 0 to 7
      &:nth-child(#{$i + 1})
        &:before
          content: ''
          @include sprite($advantages-$i)
```

Хочу использовать цикл, в нём `@include sprite($advantages-1)` - будет возвращать стили для изображения из спрайта. 
Как использовать правильно переменные, что бы на каждой итерации цикла я получал `@include sprite($advantages-1)`, `@include sprite($advantages-2)` и т.д.?

Comment: У вас где-то объявлены переменные `$advantages-1`, `$advantages-2` и так далее?

Comment: То есть, хотите ли вы в вашем коде динамически генерировать названия переменных, из которых брать значения? Если да - Sass так не может. Но то же самое можно сделать через Sass Maps: https://www.sitepoint.com/using-sass-maps/

Comment: Переменные объявлены в файле со стилями и миксином для спрайта. И да, я пытаюсь сделать генерацию имени переменной в цикле. Точней хочу разобраться. Если не затруднит, опишите решение или поделитесь любой информацией с использованием Sass Maps.

Comment: написал. Посмотрите, подошел ли вам ответ, правильно ли я понял условия.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получать значения динамически генерируемых переменных - Sass не позволяет. Но можно решить вопрос через Sass Maps:

```
@mixin sprite($index) {
  background: url($index);
}

$advantages: 'image1.jpg',
             'image2.jpg',
             'image3.jpg',
             'image4.jpg',
             'image5.jpg',
             'image6.jpg',
             'image7.jpg',
             'image8.jpg';

.image {
  position: relative;

  @for $i from 1 to length($advantages) {
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      &::before {
        @include sprite(nth($advantages, $i));
        content: '';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`$advantages` в данном случае - массив (но может быть и хешем при необходимости). В цикле через `nth($advantages, $i)` мы получаем значение определенного элемента массива, и передаем его как параметр миксину `sprite`.

[Посмотреть код на Sassmeister](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/c38131c537d7dd96b9482092942a491b).

Comment: Благодарю добрый человек за знания!